# I want to set a page of subsite as home page of its parent site. Is it possible?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sub-site, welcome-page

I want to set a page of subsite as home page of its parent site. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PowerShell. Something like this:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://yourportalurl.ru
$folder = $web.RootFolder
$folder.WelcomePage = "filter/Lists/presidents/AllItems.aspx"
$folder.Update()
```

Url of WelcomePage must be relative url (not started with "/"). In my example I set list view of subsite.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in browser settings. You could add a content editor webpart (or script editor web part, depending on your version) to the home page of the parent site that redirects to the subsite page using javascript.